# how to install another exe(only if it is not already installed) while installing winform application using windows setup in VS2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have created a window setup file for my window project in visual studio 2010. this setup file is running properly and installed the software in computer. but for running my this software i need a another exe file(filezilla server.exe) to run.So, for that i specified using custom action.So,first time when i installing my application, it also successfully installed filezilla server automatically.

But while installing second time after uninstalling my application(not filezilla server),it is again install the filezilla server.so,filezilla installation get exception while installing.

So, I want to check before installing filezilla server whether it is already installed or not.If it is installed, then no need to install filezilla server at all.otherwise, i need to install the filezilla server.

Is there any option available in windows setup in visual Studio - 2010?

Please Guide me get out of this issue?